# What am I missing in this formula?

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out why this formula is resulting in 0. The code will compile, but when I ask it to return the result of 'bloodAlc' it always says 0. I have checked for int and doubles, but as far as I know, all of the return data should be doubles.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    #include "Input_Validation_Extended.h"

int main () {
using namespace std;

ifstream qFile ("Final.txt");
string qLine;

while (!qFile.eof() ) {
    getline (qFile, qLine);
    cout << qLine << endl;

} 
qFile.close();

char gender;
double genderConst, weight, percentAlc, hours, ounces, bloodAlc, alcType;
double beer, wine, spirits; 
weight = 0;
hours = 0;
ounces = 0;
bloodAlc = 0.0;
cout << "Please enter your weight in pounds: \n";
cin >> weight;

cout << "Please enter your gender: \n";
cin >> gender;

cout << "Please enter the amount of hours you have been drinking: \n";
cin >> hours;

cout << "How many drinks have you had: ";
cin >> ounces;

cout << "Please choose A, B, or C for the type of beverage you are enjoying: ";
cin >> alcType;

if (gender == 'F' || gender == 'f')
{
    genderConst = .66;
}
else if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')
{
    genderConst = .73;
}   
if (alcType == 'A' || alcType == 'a')
{
beer = (12.0 * ounces);
bloodAlc = ((beer * 5.14) / (weight * genderConst)) - (.015 * hours);
}
else if (alcType == 'B' || alcType == 'b')
{
wine = (5.0 * ounces);
bloodAlc = ((wine * 5.14) / (weight * genderConst)) - (.015 * hours);
}

 cout << "Your BAC is: " << bloodAlc;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of gender?

Comment: It'd be a good time to learn how to use an interactive debugger, or failing that add some extra `cout << "some var = " << some_var << '\n';` statements throughout your code so you can see what's read in and calculated correctly.  One obvious issue is that there's no `else if` case handling `alcType` C.  Another tip: you can use `if (cin >> my_var) cout << "my_var value read is " << my_var << '\n'; else { cerr << "failed to read my_var\n"; exit(1); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `alcType` as `double`, but you use it like a `char`:

```
double genderConst, weight, percentAlc, hours, ounces, bloodAlc, alcType;
...
if (alcType == 'A' || alcType == 'a')
```

So none of the `if (alcType == 'A'..)`-paths will be entered, and `bloodAlc` remains `0.0`.

Change `double alcType` to `char alcType`, and it should work.
If not, please use a debugger :-)

Comment: @Tyger: yes, but not `alcType`. If you scan into a double value and enter `A`, then the result is "unchanged", because `cin` will interpret `A` as an invalid number (and will not scan in anything at all).

Comment: sorry I get it now I made a mistake I put `if (v = 'A')`  which is always true. thank you

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That worked.